# VS 2010 and TFS 2005 compatibility

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, compatibility, tfs-2005

We are currently in a position to move up from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010.  Unfortunately, we don't have a server allocated for a TFS upgrade yet (should happen in about 6 months), so we are stuck with TFS 2005 for now.  Will VS2010 be compatible with TFS 2005?  If so, any potential issues we need to consider?

Comment: Can't you upgrade your current TFS server?

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio and Team Explorer 2010 do not officially support TFS 2005 servers (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997788.aspx for the compat matrix).  I don't think it is actively blocked, though, and it may work just fine for the mainstream scenarios.  I don't have TFS 2005 server to try it.

Answer (score 1):

Currently using VS2010 and TFS2005 here and they work well together.